# Cheapest way to get a CAN signal

Tags: spi, i2c, can

I have to transfer signals over around five meters. My input signals are I2C or SPI-compatible, but unfortunately it is no good idea to transmit them over such a long distance. Therefore I was thinking of converting the I2C- or SPI-signal to a CAN-signal (and back). What is the best approach of converting these signals into each other without having to use (too much) external components? My first approach was to use a MCP2515, but there I already need an external clock. Is there a cheaper way to do that?

Comment: Why to you think it's a bad idea to use I2C or SPI for this distance?

Comment: I have seen UARTS run as fast as possible to act as parallel to serial and serial to parallel converters to form links over pairs of fiber. I'd try small MCUs today using internal oscillators and of course it doesn't have to be fiber . Ok on slow SPI but I'm not sure I2C could run like that....

Comment: @sweber: Have read that I can get errors if I use SPI over large distance I can get read/write errors...

Comment: As long as you get the line capacitance correct (and choose the correct pull-up resistors) I2C should be fine too.

Comment: What speed (bits/sec) are we talking about?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Don't know exactly yet, but for first tests I assume around 1kbit/sec or more

Comment: Based on the bitrate * distance < 10^8 rule of thumb with RS-485, you should be able to push up to 20 MBit through a 5m cable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a problem with serial protocols like SPI over 5 metres then the simple answer is to lower the clocking rate for receiving data back from remote devices. Going to something like CAN is not a simple solution to my way of thinking but of course this may need to be done if distances warrant it and you can't lower speed BUT think about this....

Putting a micro at both ends (or the remote end) to allow CAN type communications means your overall throughput of retrieving data from a remote device is going to be limited without going to a significantly higher data rate over the CAN link and you'll have to tailor your current master SPI transmission to be compatible with CAN and this might mean that instead of just sending an SPI clock and CE you'll have to send a more formal request for the remote data to be passed back to you.

Simplest way is to reduce the clock speed to suit the cable and, if necessary use balanced drivers and receivers i.e. make everything work with the delay that you get by introducing the 5 metres of cable. It's easy when sending data out to a remote device - both clock and data arrive largely in sync but trying to get data back is the real problem on long distances - the receiving device gets the clock and syncs up it's data with the incoming clk but by the time it arrives back at the master things are skewed with respect to each other.

That is why I suggest considering clock speed reduction - the skews won't be as bad (as a percentage) and are less likely to give errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you can spare an extra twisted pair, you could go with RS485. You'd use two twisted pair, one for data and one for direction control, or you could go half-duplex with a pair for each direction.

In the case of data/direction, you'd use the direction control line to disable the output at the slave end when transmitting to it, and disable the master output when the slave is expected to be transmitting.

Comment: Why use data/direction for half-duplex when the same cable can do data/data in full-duplex?  Maybe if the hardware on one or both ends is already half only, but if you're making the hardware...

Comment: The same twisted pair can operate full duplex, but there is nothing to prevent bus contention.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation trying to send a signal over i2c, but my distance was much further. I was using CAT5 cable. I had a rather hokey setup to test the idea. I had setup a circuit to use an i2c extender chip (this was to get 2 arduinos to talk to each other). I think I fried one or both of the chips at some point, so I just wired across the circuit (I pulled out the chips out of their dip sockets and ran very short jumper wires across basically crisscrossing the LxSy and SxLy lines). Anyway, without going into too much detail I could get the signal through about 100 ft. of CAT5. You might want to try before you give up or assume it won't work. Otherwise you can try the various i2c bus extender chips out there. The circuits are simple and the chips don't cost a bunch (TI and NXP make them P82B715PN). This link (in French) is what I went off of [i2c bus extender circuit](http://mchobby.be/wiki/index.php?title=P82B715PN:_I2C_Bus_Extender-Montage)